# How to identify if a string contains even integers by using regular expression (regex)

Tags: python, regex

Right now I got:

```
import re
print(bool(re.match("^\d*[02468]$","123")))
```

The code I wrote can only determine if this number "123" is even or not, but I would like the output to be "True" because it contains one even integer "2".

Comment: Change the pattern to ```"^.*[02468]{1,}.*$"``` , also no need to use bool function . You can just say - ```if re.match("^.*[02468]{1,}.*$","13jkjkjk2@#@4a"): <do something>```

Comment: Would you like it to return `True` if any number in the string is even?

Comment: Hi Freddy: yes, that is what I want

Comment: @Olivia You can also use ``re.search``: ``if re.search(r'[02468]', '123'): # do something``